# Maximize (Fullscreen) MainWindow of a Process through C# and user32

Tags: c#, user32, maximize, showwindow

I am using:

```
private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

To try and maximize another window on the current computer. However, this "Maximize" only makes the window the size of the screen and doesn't really full screen it.

When I click the maximize button on the application, it will fill the screen and become borderless and cannot be moved unless you restore it.

This does not happen when I use the maximize function with ShowWindow.

Is there another way?

Comment: You'll have to change the window style flags to remove the border, SetWindowLongPtr().  Not giving the program a heart attack doing so is a bit unlikely.

Comment: That's not what I am looking to do. It's strange that the "Maximize" function just makes the window the size of the screen, but does not Maximize like the button does.